# How to stop HighCharts/HighStock from displaying things with the completely wrong dates?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For a very long time, I've been repeatedly forced to stop using HighCharts/HighStock because every label has the completely wrong date, no matter what I do or try. Even when copying the exact format from their example: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/flags-general

Even in their example, it CLEARLY says "11" for the month, yet the thing says "December"?!

In my own code, I have: `{ x: Date.UTC(2013, 3, 27), ...` and it shows as `Saturday, Apr 27, 2013` in the browser. What?

And other times, it seems to mess up the day instead of the month. It makes absolutely no sense. It's maddening and makes me feel as if I can't trust anything that this library produces, but I also have no other choice but to use it, especially given the countless hours I've plown into trying to force it to work...

Setting `useUTC: false` or `useUTC: true` appears to have no effect whatsoever, but even if it did, it makes no sense for it to get the entire month wrong.

It apparently requires some third-party "Moment.js" library just to set the timezone, so I've been unable to try that setting.

What am I supposedly doing wrong? Why is it not displaying things correctly?

Comment: Have you ever red the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC#parameters) for `Date.UTC()`? Read about the Month parameter in particular.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I didn't even realize that this was part of JS as opposed to HighCharts... That explains a lot. But it's very strange that they start with 0 in this situation...

Comment: A legacy we all live with.

Comment: @RandyCasburn That's very evil of them, especially as the *day* one starts with 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highcharts dispalys dates correctly, according to `Date.UTC` documentation:

> **month** Optional
>
> An integer between 0 (January) and 11 (December) representing the month. (...)

---

> **day** Optional
>
> An integer between 1 and 31 representing the day of the month. If omitted, defaults to 1.

---

**Docs:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC#parameters